# Amount of trials until all marbles have shown in a box of different marbles.

Tags: statistics

We have 81.000 different marbles in a box. With every grab, I get 30 different marbles out of the box. After this, the 30 marbles have to be thrown back into the box so that there are again 81.000 different marbles.

How often do I have to grab into the box until I have statistically seen at least one time every single marble of these 81000 different marbles?

Hope someone could help me with this question. Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but one interpretation is that we would like to know how many grabs are required, on average, to have drawn each marble at least once.

A simplifying assumption seems appropriate here.  I think we may as sell assume that grabbing a batch of $30$ marbles is about the same as drawing $30$ marbles one at a time with replacement, because the probability that $30$ marbles drawn one at a time are not all distinct is quite small--about $0.005$.

If we draw the marbles one at a time, then we have [The Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Calculating_the_expectation) with $n=81,000$ coupons.  A well-known approximation for the expected number of draws required to get a complete set of coupons (i.e., marbles) is
$$n \ln n + \gamma n + 0.5$$
where $\gamma \approx 0.5772$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.  If we plug $n=81,000$ into this formula, we find that on average about $960,000$ draws are required.  But those are single-marble draws, so if we grab batches of $30$ marbles then $960,000 / 30 =32,000$ grabs are required.